# Crear / añadir posición en layout de Joomla 3

Tags: php, joomla3

Estoy integrando un template en Joomla 3 y requiero crear una posición en un layout del componente **com_content**. Estoy consiente que para eso en el archivo **index.php** del template se puede hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="nombre-posicion" />
```

En cambio eso no funciona dentro de los layouts.

---

Encontré lo siguiente en la documentación oficial de Joomla:

> **[How do you put a module inside an article? - Joomla! Documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article%3F)**
>
> Syntax:
>
> - {loadposition position[, style]}
> - {loadmodule module[, title[, style]]}

Pero detecté que sólo funciona al utilizar ese código dentro del contenido de los artículos (el cual es guardado en DB y luego parseado para ser mostrado en el frontend).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esa no es la forma "correcta" de hacerlo. Lo ideal es tener declaraciones jdoc en el código de la plantilla. Si usas el "Modules Anywhere" estarás usando una especie de "hack", pues básicamente usas un plugin de sistema para modificar la salida del frontend.

Para hacerlo "correctamente", tienes abundante información sobre la creación de plantillas en la documentación oficial (y en español):

https://docs.joomla.org/Portal:Template_Development/es

Concretamente, los distintos tipos de jdoc se explican aquí

https://docs.joomla.org/Jdoc_statements/es

Siento no haber contestado antes, espero que aún pueda servirte de algo :).

EDITO:

Vaya, está claro que no tenía la comprensión lectora activada cuando he contestado... veo que lo que quieres es meter un módulo en com_content, no en la plantilla. En ese caso, el modules anywhere sí puede ser una buena opción, aunque sigue habiendo una posibilidad de hacerlo con código:

```
$myModules = JModuleHelper::getModules('my-position);
```

con eso obtienes los módulos que haya en esa posición específica. Y luego para mostrarlos:

```
<?php foreach ($myModules as $module) : ?>
    <?php echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module) ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Encontré la solución con el uso de un plugin llamado [Modules Anywhere](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/modules-anywhere). Éste añade funcionalidad al core de Joomla para que sea donde se coloque la etiqueta para llamar al módulo (tipo Joomla) este lo parseará y renderizará.

Ejemplos de como llamar módulos:

```
{module Some module}
{module 123}
{module Main Menu|division}
{modulepos position-7}
```